# what is maximum ram capacity of my laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, ramdisk

I have Hp 15-d107tx notebook pc. It have 4GB of ram and I want to upgrade it to 8GB but i don't know how much my laptop support. I checked inside my laptop, It have 2 slots for RAM and **[elpida 4gb 1rx8 pc3l-12800s-11-12-b4](https://photos.app.goo.gl/KrDRFcKeoHox6Dif1)** This RAM is installed in my laptop.

Comment: yes you can use any company. But make sure Speed and DDR3L is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another 4GB with same.
Only Make sure its 4GB DDR3L (L indicates Low voltage RAM).

Try to purchase same speed of 1280MHZ. Max Speed it support is 1600MHZ.

Comment: which one should i buy 1280Mhz or 1600Mhz?

Comment: and also SODIMM OR DIMM?

Comment: Get the same Mhz of the existing one.

Comment: 1600Mhz supports your Laptop as official site. SODIMM

Comment: i cannot find 1280Mhz ram.

Comment: Download `CPU-Z` [Download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zRvOw8HzDuN1hoQVA1TEFPZFU/view?usp=sharing)  Run that Exe.

Go to SPD tab you can check all details if can attach the screen shot

Comment: [screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwTgYzZKuzAZa2xZT3pMcHljaDg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Go for [this](http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-original-204-pin-VOLTAGE-PC3L-12800S/dp/B00J2KGP6M?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=a5e8600b-1720-4e22-85d9-2fbaa9a0377b).

Make sure you get PCL. Because L is most Important.

If you want Elpida you dont have shipping for India in online. Better you go to nearest store and Purchase.

Comment: One last question can I use 8 GB ram instead of 4 GB so that it will make total of 12 GB ram in my laptop?

Comment: Yes. You can go ahead it's support upto 16 GB 8 GB x 2

Comment: can i use [hyperX impact](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX316LS9IB_4.pdf)  or [corsair](http://www.corsair.com/en-ww/corsair-memory-8gb-ddr3l-sodimm-memory-cmso8gx3m1c1600c11) RAMS.?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two slots, and one slot has a 4GB RAM module in it, then the other will accept 4GB as well. However, you want to know if it can accept 8GB per module or even more. The HP specs page doesn't give much info, doesn't tell the maximum allowed amount of RAM. The following page says it can work with 16GB total, so two modules of 8GB RAM.

https://www.91mobiles.com/hp-15-d107tx-g8d80pa-core-i3-4th-gen-4-gb-500-gb-dos-laptop-price-in-india-65665

This one says 16GB as well:

https://www.snapdeal.com/product/hp-15d107tx-notebook-4th-gen/46397291

This means that it will probably work with one 4GB and one 8GB module, so 12GB total. Having two identical modules will probably speed things up, so if 8GB is enough, that is cheaper and faster.